# Mass of sucrose solutions

Tags: chemical-biology

What is the mass of 150 ml of 40% sucrose, and what is the mass of 150 ml of 20% sucrose? I don't know exactly how to figure it out without using a device to tell me the mass. All I know is the mass of 10 ml of 40% sucrose, which is about 15.7 grams.

Comment: If the water volume was additive you could do it by adding more water w/ known density...  But it's not, is it...

Answer (score 2):

If 10ml of 40% sucrose is 15.7 grams, then the mass of 150 ml of 40% sucrose is

$$ 15 \times 15.7 grams$$

You can not determine the mass of 150 ml of 20% sucrose from the information given.

You could calculate from this sucrose solution density table:
http://homepages.gac.edu/~cellab/chpts/chpt3/table3-2.html

Note that the table shows the premise "I know is the mass of 10 ml of 40% sucrose, which is about 15.7 grams" to be incorrect.